# is there a way to change the background color of a specific word in outlined text field jetpack compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, textfield, background-color, android-compose-textfield

I am looking for a way to change the background color of certain words in outlined text field while typing, but I couldn't find a way to achieve that yet. Does anyone know a way to do this? (Preferably in compose but other solutions are also OK.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the **`VisualTransformation`** property in the `TextField` to change the text while typing. Use an `AnnotatedString` to apply different `SpanStyle` to your text.

Something like:

```
OutlinedTextField(
    value = text,
    onValueChange = { text = it },
    visualTransformation = ColorsTransformation()
)

class ColorsTransformation() : VisualTransformation {
    override fun filter(text: AnnotatedString): TransformedText {
        return TransformedText(
            buildAnnotatedStringWithColors(text.toString()),
            OffsetMapping.Identity)
    }
}
```

In the `buildAnnotatedStringWithColors` you can move your logic to change the background color of certain words. It is just an example to change the color for each word.

```
fun buildAnnotatedStringWithColors(text:String): AnnotatedString{

    //it is just an example
    
    val words: List<String> = text.split("\\s+".toRegex())// splits by whitespace
    val builder = AnnotatedString.Builder()

    val colors = listOf(Color.Red,Color.Black,Color.Yellow,Color.Blue)
    var count = 0

    for (word in words) {
        //Use you favorite SpanStyle
        builder.withStyle(style = SpanStyle(
            background = colors[count % 4],
            color = White
        )) {
            append("$word ")
        }
        count ++
    }
    return builder.toAnnotatedString()
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response! that's exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Hi Gabriele. Thanks for your answer. I want to know one more. Is there any way to insert inlineContent in TextField? I want to insert some image or icon between letters in TextField. Because SpanStyle caanot modify text border, I have to insert icon or image.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is using annotated string:

```
Text(buildAnnotatedString {
    append("Hello ")

    withStyle(
        style = SpanStyle(
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
            color = Color.White,
            background = Color.Blue,
        )
    ) {
        append("World")
    }
}, modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp))
```

Result

[image]

---

Also take a look at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68848641/3585796), which will allow you to use a more complex drawing like this:

[image]