# Add small padding/margin between text with AnnotatedString

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Whenever I use the **buildAnnotatedString** I must write some sort of style using `ParagraphStyle` or `SpanStlye`. Sadly none of these 2 classes have modifiers to add some padding between every text (append)

This is what I'm getting right now. **There should a small space between the background and the letters at the start and at the end of every text:**

[image]

This is the code with the background:

```
val spanStyle = (
    MaterialTheme.typography.body1.copy(
     color = MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface,
     fontWeight = FontWeight.W400,
     fontSize = 17.sp,
     letterSpacing = 0.25.sp,
     background = MaterialTheme.colors.surface,
     baselineShift = BaselineShift(0.2f),
)).toSpanStyle()

buildAnnotatedString {
    withStyle(style = spanStyle) {
         append("I write text here with background")
    }
}
```

I've checked `ParagraphStyle` but the only thing related to vertical space is the `lineHeight` which obviously increase the height of every line but not the space between them.

Is there any way to add this little small space between every append() so background isn't coupled?

Edit:
**This is what I have right now:**
[image]

**This is what I want to achieve**, the horizontal padding at the start and end inside. TextIndent doesn't work because there's not a separation between the start background and start text.
[image]

Comment: Why not add " " empty space or `.padding()` to Modifier when you know there is background?

Comment: Are you using **monospace** font? If so, adding spaces would be a good idea.

Comment: Adding spaces create too much space which I don't want, also where do you add the .padding() modifier in a SpanStyle? @JemshitIskenderov

Comment: Sadly I'm not using monospace font, if you mean to use letterSpacing I don't think it's a good idea @Darkman

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible with system methods, but you can draw background manually.

I'm adding only sample code here, fore more details of implementation see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68848641/3585796).

```
@Composable
fun TestScreen(
) {
    val baselineShiftMultiplier = 0.2f
    val lineHeightMultiplier = 1.7f
    val spanStyle = MaterialTheme.typography.body1.copy(
        color = MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.W400,
        fontSize = 17.sp,
        letterSpacing = 0.25.sp,
        baselineShift = BaselineShift(baselineShiftMultiplier),
    )
    var selectedPartPaths by remember { mutableStateOf(Path()) }
    Text(
        buildAnnotatedString {
            withStyle(ParagraphStyle(lineHeight = spanStyle.fontSize * lineHeightMultiplier)) {
                append("I write text here\n")
                withStyle(style = spanStyle.toSpanStyle()) {
                    append("I write text here with background\n")
                    append("I write text here with background\n")
                }
                append("I write text here\n")
                withStyle(style = spanStyle.toSpanStyle()) {
                    append("I write text here with background\n")
                }
                append("I write text here\n")
            }
        },
        onTextLayout = { layoutResult ->
            selectedPartPaths = Path().apply {
                layoutResult.layoutInput.text.spanStyles.forEach { spanRange ->
                    val boundingBoxes = layoutResult
                        .getBoundingBoxesForRange(
                            start = spanRange.start,
                            end = spanRange.end
                        )
                    for (i in boundingBoxes.indices) {
                        val boundingBox = boundingBoxes[i]
                        addRect(
                            boundingBox.copy(
                                top = boundingBox.top + boundingBox.height * (1 - 1 / lineHeightMultiplier - baselineShiftMultiplier),
                            )
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        modifier = Modifier.drawBehind {
            drawPath(selectedPartPaths, style = Fill, color = Color.LightGray)
        }
    )
}

fun TextLayoutResult.getBoundingBoxesForRange(start: Int, end: Int): List<Rect> {
    var prevRect: Rect? = null
    var firstLineCharRect: Rect? = null
    val boundingBoxes = mutableListOf<Rect>()
    for (i in start..end) {
        val rect = getBoundingBox(i)
        val isLastRect = i == end

        // single char case
        if (isLastRect && firstLineCharRect == null) {
            firstLineCharRect = rect
            prevRect = rect
        }

        // `rect.right` is zero for the last space in each line
        // looks like an issue to me, reported: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/197146630
        if (!isLastRect && rect.right == 0f) continue

        if (firstLineCharRect == null) {
            firstLineCharRect = rect
        } else if (prevRect != null) {
            if (prevRect.bottom != rect.bottom || isLastRect) {
                boundingBoxes.add(
                    firstLineCharRect.copy(right = prevRect.right)
                )
                firstLineCharRect = rect
            }
        }
        prevRect = rect
    }
    return boundingBoxes
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Sorry maybe I didn't explain myself correctly, I meant to say the horizontal padding (start, end) so there's a small padding like this -> '-I write text here with background-' where the '-' is the small padding. I don't set an empty space because it takes too much space.

Comment: But maybe I can make it work with the boxes bounding thing, I need to take a deep look at that code

Comment: @Barrufet If you need to shift the background, you can do that with bounding boxes as I showed, but if you need to shift the text itself, the only option is to use `ParagraphStyle.textIndent`: yet that will only apply to the beginning of the line. I'm still not sure what your result should look like. Please update your question with details, including a screen of the expected result, which you can do in any image editor.

Comment: I've updated it which the result I'm trying to achieve, sadly this onTextLayout requires a lot of work and lags my visual ui in every recompose (Yeah it recomposes because background color changes to other color). I don't think it's a good idea but good to know this exists