# Styling specific line of Text on Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

So, it's kind of a simple styling.

```
Text(
    text = "some text which can extends to many lines"
)
```

how would someone build an [annotated string](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/AnnotatedString) to style only specif lines of the text? And by line I mean what it's actually rendering as a line - and not something predefined as a list of sub strings.

I've imagine to make a use of combined [textLayoutResult](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/TextLayoutResult) with the annotated capability, but by reading the documentation I don't have much clue how to do so.

The plan was to the `TextLayoutResult` to retrieve the number of lines rendered on text. Then, it should be theoretically possible to retrieve the sub string on each of the lines rendered. And by pushing them on the annotated processor, the desired results would be achieved.

What am I missing?

Comment: Yes, I have. Couldn't find instructions on it

Comment: Generally your idea about TextLayoutResult is correct. You can search SO for question using `TextLayoutResult`, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68848641/3585796), to get an idea how to use it. It's unclear how exactly you wanna style it, so it's hard to give you an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've read before the question, but it suffers with some problems: you have to statically defined which part of text you will styled, and the style of texts are drawn based on a Canvas, and not basic things as changing the color of the text. But I'm gonna be looking for a solution in the mean time

Comment: This is more of an example of how you can get information from a TextLayoutResult. You can use `buildAnnotatedString` depending on the collected results.

Comment: Yeah, I have an idea. If it works, I share it here.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to achieve the desired effect.

For those who want to do, you will need at least:

- Two Text components;
- A mutable state to keep track of offset on the text;

You limit the first Text by the number of `maxLines - 1` and uses `TextLayoutResult` to retrieve the last offset of the last line. Then, you just update the state on the composable and create another Text component with the substring which starts from the last one. Then, you can apply the filters that you wish on this one.

Repeate the process for as many lines as you wish.